# Error de SaveChanges entity framework 6 con dos entidades

Tags: mvc, entity-framework-6

Estoy intentado guardar una entidad Nota desde el `controller -> servicio -> repository` y da error de `DbEntityValidationException` y lo pinto por pantalla pero a continuación estoy guardando las estadísticas de la web y cuando intentado hacer el `SaveChanges` salta otra vez el `DbEntityValidationException` pero de la entidad Nota, ¿cómo puede ser?

Los dos llaman al mismo código.

los dos le llaman desde su servicio correspondiente.

```
Controller -> Servicio -> Repository (Notas)
ControllerBase -> Servicio -> Repository (Estadisticas)
```

```
_EstadisticasRepository.Add(item);
Save();




 private void Save()
        {
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
        }



 public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            dbset.Add(entity);
        }



 public virtual void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                // Exception raise =  dbEx;
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                            validationErrors.Entry.Entity.ToString(),
                            validationError.ErrorMessage);
                        // raise a new exception nesting
                        // the current instance as InnerException
                        errorMessage += message;
                        //raise = new InvalidOperationException(message, raise);
                    }
                }
                throw new Exception(errorMessage, dbEx);
                //throw raise;
            }

        }
```

Log de Errores:

> StackTrace: en
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() en
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() en
>   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() en
>   AscarizWeb.Data.Models.WebCodeEntities.Commit() en
>   C:\Users\rodrigo.ascariz\ProyectoWebTFS\AscarizWeb\Main\AscarizWeb.Data\Models\WebCodeEntities.cs:línea
>   25 InnerException : NULL ExceptionMessage: Error de validación para
>   una o varias entidades. Vea la propiedad 'EntityValidationErrors' para
>   obtener más detalles.

Comment: DbEntityValidationException: Favor de incluir los detalles del error (ExceptionMessage, InnerException y StackTrace)

Comment: StackTrace:
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   en System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   en System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   en AscarizWeb.Data.Models.WebCodeEntities.Commit() en C:\Users\rodrigo.ascariz\ProyectoWebTFS\AscarizWeb\Main\AscarizWeb.Data\Models\WebCodeEntities.cs:línea 25 InnerException : NULL ExceptionMessage: Error de validación para una o varias entidades. Vea la propiedad 'EntityValidationErrors' para obtener más detalles.